# Solr configuration for scored search

Tags: solr, solr6

I am trying to setup a Solr index for searching against a database of product information. For this purpose, I have populated a database of product details and used Solr 6.0.0. For a given product detail (title, brand, other keywords), I would like to know if there is a product in the database that closely matches the given details. I have started dataimport and created the index. However, when I search, the scores of the matching product are all the same in spite of the products listed being different. I have tried with different combinations of search keywords, but the result is similar in every case. I have also tried using different Tokenizers and Filters.

Sample of `schema.xml` I have tried is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<schema name="example" version="1.5">
 <field name="id" type="Int"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="name" type="text_general"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="brand" type="text_general"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="category" type="text_general"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
  <field name="catchall" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    <copyField source="id" dest="catchall" />
    <copyField source="name" dest="catchall" />
    <copyField source="brand" dest="catchall" />
    <copyField source="category" dest="catchall" />
    <copyField source="description" dest="catchall" />
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
    <defaultSearchField>catchall</defaultSearchField>
    <types>
        <fieldtype name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
        <fieldtype name="Int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
        <fieldtype name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
          <analyzer type="index">
            <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1" 
                    splitOnNumerics="1"
                    splitOnCaseChange="1"
                    generateNumberParts="1"
                    catenateWords="0"
                    catenateNumbers="0"
                    catenateAll="0"
                    preserveOriginal="1"
                    />

            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
          <analyzer type="query">
            <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1" 
                    splitOnNumerics="1"
                    splitOnCaseChange="1"
                    generateNumberParts="1"
                    catenateWords="0"
                    catenateNumbers="0"
                    catenateAll="0"
                    preserveOriginal="1"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
        </fieldtype>
        <fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.StrField" />
    </types>
</schema>
```

**Edit**

The entity definition from `data-config.xml` is as below

```
<entity name="master_products"  
    pk="id"
    query="select p.* ,b.*  from master_products p ,master_brands b  where b.id=p.brand_id"
    deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM master_products WHERE product_name='${dataimporter.delta.product_name}' "
    >
    <!-- or b.brnad='${dataimporter.delta.brand}' -->

     <field column="product_name" name="name"/> 
     <field column="product_description" name="description"/> 
     <field column="id" name="id"/>
     <field column="mrp" name="mrp"/> 
     <field column="brand" name="brand"/>


  <entity name="master_brands" 
    query="select * from master_brands"
    deltaImportQuery="select * from master_brands where id ={master_products.brand_id}" processor="SqlEntityProcessor" cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache" >

  </entity>

  <entity name="master_product_categories" 
    query="select * from master_product_categories"
    deltaImportQuery="select * from master_product_categories where id ={master_products.   product_category_id}" processor="SqlEntityProcessor" cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache" >
    <field column="category" name="category" />
  </entity>

 </entity>
```

***Edit***
The query is as below.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/myproducts/select?fl=* score&fq=brand:Nikon&fq=mrp:28950*&indent=on&q=name:*"Nikon D3200 (Black) DSLR with  AF-S 18-55mm VR Kit Lens"*&wt=json
```

I would like help in achieving my goal. Can you please direct me to creating the proper configuration that would meet my purpose? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you querying the index?

Comment: post has been updated  with the query details.

Comment: But you're not showing what the query (what the settings are when you're retrieving documents) is, just how you're importing data. The query is usually the relevant part when it comes to scoring.

Comment: post has been updated with the query details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wildcard queries are constant scoring](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax), meaning that they won't change the score of the documents that match. You probably want to use regular querying (and not wildcards) to get proper scoring between documents.

> Range queries [a TO z], prefix queries a*, and wildcard queries a*b are constant-scoring (all matching documents get an equal score). The scoring factors tf, idf, index boost, and coord are not used. There is no limitation on the number of terms that match (as there was in past versions of Lucene).

`fq` terms does not affect score, they just filter the result set.