# No matches when mixing keywords

Tags: solr

I am trying to do a product search setup using Solr. It does return results for keywords that follow the same order in the product name. However, when the keywords are mixed up, no results are returned. I would like to get results with scores that closely match the given keywords in any order.

My question on [scoring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37726365/6445351) has the schema, data configuration and query. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your query? This might happen if you enclose the search terms in quotes (eg. q=name:"product+name" instead of q=name:product+name)

Comment: Thank You very much...its works ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you enter your query as a regular query, instead of using wildcards, any hits in a `text_general` field as you've defined should be returned.

You [can use the `mm` parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm(MinimumShouldMatch)Parameter) to adjust how many of the terms supplied that need to match from a query. I suggest using the [edismax query parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser), as that allows you do to more "natural" queries instead of having to add the fieldnames in the query itself:

```
defType=edismax&qf=catchall&q=nikon dslr
defType=edismax&qf=catchall&q=dslr nikon
```

should both give the same set of documents (but possibly different scores when using phrase boosts).

Comment: Thanks for the help.